# node-postgres library : How to avoid race condition with event driven database insertion?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm currentling facing a race condition issue with db insertion.

I try to simplify my original code to try explaining the issue.
(i hope i didn't brought errors in the rewriting process)

** Main Program **

```
var pool = new pg.Pool({
    database: 'DB',
    user: 'User',
    password: 'Password'
});

conn.on('someEvent', async function(e) {

     var param1 = e.getHeader('param1');
     var param2 = e.getHeader('param2'); 
     var myObj = new MYOBJ(null);

     var params:{
         param1:param1,
         param2:param2
     }
    
     await myObj.InsertInPQ(pool,params);
})
```

** A custom object i created to access the DB **

```
myObj.prototype.insertInPQ = async function(pool,params) {
    
    var myObj=this;
    
    try {

        console.log("ENTERING myObj.insertInDB() with param1:"+params.param1+" and  param2:"+params.param2);

        var query=  "INSERT INTO schema.SOMETABLE "+
                    "VALUES ($1,$2)"    
            
        const { rows } = await pool.query(query,[params.param1,params.param2]);
        return (true);  
    }
    catch(err){
        throw new Error("myObj.insertInDB() for param1:"+params.param1+" and params2:"+params.param2+" error:"+err)
    }
};
```

Let's now say eventA and eventB happen almost simustanously with :

eventA: param1=1, param2=2
eventB: param1=3 param2=4

On eventA :

console will display : ENTERING myObj.insertInDB() with param1=1 and  param2=2
DB inserttion will be fine.

On eventB :
console will display : ENTERING myObj.insertInDB() with param1=3 and param2=4

But postgres logs will report inserting a row with the eventA values (1,2).

I don't understand how nodejs and the pg library runs under the hood, and what i should do to avoid this kind of problems (which are, by the way, unpermanent, so very hard to troubleshout).

Anybody have a suggestion ?

Regards,

Yaducam

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you saying that eventB is lost? What postgres logs are you looking at?

Comment: please check some example's here [link](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions) I myself currently researching on race-condition's

Comment: "*postgres logs will report inserting a row with the eventA values (1,2)*" - that won't happen unless you either fire eventA twice, or you already had these values in the `SOMETABLE`. Either way, the eventB will not be affected, there is no race condition here. And no, you don't need transactions for a single-statement insertion.